# AsyncTaskLoader vs AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-loadermanager

Since `Honeycomb` and the `v4 Compatibility Library` it is possible to use `AsyncTaskLoader`. From what I understand, the `AsyncTaskLoader` can survive through config changes like screen flips.

Is it recommended to use `AsyncTaskLoader` instead of `AsyncTask`? Does `LoaderManager` get in the picture too?

But I haven't found any good example(s) about how to correctly use the `AsyncTaskLoader`. The docs also provide no examples. Can anyone provide some good examples.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can have a look at the compatibility library's source code to get more info. What a `FragmentActivity` does is:

- keep a list of `LoaderManager`'s
- make sure they don't get destroyed when you flip your phone (or another configuration change occurs) by saving instances using `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()`
- kick the right loader when you call `initLoader()` in your Activity

You need to use the `LoaderManager` to interface with the loaders, and provide the needed callbacks to create your loader(s) and populate your views with the data they return.

Generally it should be easier than managing `AsyncTask`'s yourself. However, `AsyncTaskLoader` is not exactly well documented, so you should study the example in the docs and/or model your code after `CursorLoader`.

Comment: I will have a look at this. Maybe it is too early to find good examples about `AsyncTaskLoader`, and when more developers start using it, more examples will come.

Answer (score 51):

Comparing **AsyncTaskLoader** vs. **AsyncTask**, as you may know, when you rotate your device screen, it may destroy and re-create your activity. To make it clear. let's imagine rotating your device while networking transaction is going on:

**AsyncTask** will be re-executed as a background thread again, and the previous background thread processing will just be redundant and zombie.

**AsyncTaskLoader** will just be re-used basing on Loader ID that was registered in Loader Manager before, so re-executing network transaction will be avoided.

In summary, **AsyncTaskLoader** prevents duplication of background threads and eliminates duplication of zombie activities.

Answer (score 11):

**AsyncTaskLoader** performs the same function as the **AsyncTask**, but a bit better. It can handle Activity configuration changes more easily, and it behaves within the life cycles of Fragments and Activities. The nice thing is that the AsyncTaskLoader can be used in any situation that the AsyncTask is being used. Anytime data needs to be loaded into memory for the Activity/Fragment to handle, The AsyncTaskLoader can do the job better.

There are a few issues with using AsyncTasks, though:

- Configuration changes can mess things up
- Pausing an activity doesn’t pause the AsyncTask
- A fair amount of boilerplate code (which means more possible errors)

[AsyncTaskLoader doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html)

Answer (score 8):

Some differences other than described in other answers:

When using **AsyncTaskLoader** over **AsyncTask**:

- **AsyncTaskLoader** gives us liberty to load old cached data until new data is returned by `forceLoad()`
- We can set delays to **AsyncTaskLoader** by `setUpdateThrottle()` which can prevent consecutive updates to client (Activity/Fragment)
- **AsyncTaskLoader** can be shared to multiple fragments if they have common parent activity and if it was started from `getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager()`
- **AsyncTaskLoader** is destroyed by `LoaderManger` when its linked activity is no more available. while we need to manually destroy **AsyncTasks** if its caller activity destroys. This saves our time from writing all the clearing stuff. AsyncTaskLoader plays well with their respective lifecycles.

So, AsyncTaskLoader is way better than AsyncTask.