# Make multiple HTTP  Requests with Loader 

Tags: android, asynchronous

I read the documentation of `Loader` and it was written that a `LoaderManager` can have multiple loaders which can be identified through id's . But I have a confusion that if I want to make 5 or 6 `HTTP requests` asynchronously, how can I use multiple loaders for this. What I'm thinking is every time I want to make a new `HTTP request`, I'll get a new `instance` of class that is implementing `AsyncTaskLoader`. An example would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not use an `AsyncTask` and simply create a new task for each new requests?

Comment: It's every where that loaders are more efficient than AsyncTask. So in order to learn loaders I was trying to modify my project.

Comment: [AsyncTaskLoader](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7122836/726863) mostly deal with Fragments and also have several dis-advantages.

Comment: So you mean that we should use AsyncTask instead of AsyncTaskLoader. I had a doubt that if they have introduced loaders, the AsyncTask might be deprecated in future.

Comment: http://blog.gunawan.me/2011/10/android-asynctaskloader-exception.html..... https://gist.github.com/2949121

Comment: http://blog.sleepybear.us/2012/02/loading-loading-loading.html