# Best place to run asynctask in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I have thinking some time about this. I have an FragmentActivity in wich I have a FrameLayout and some Fragments change there. Each fragment has different layout and launches different asynctask. My question is :

Where is the best place, I mean best fragment state, to call asynctask ? I mean like I have some textviews in fragment layout and I want them to display text values based on asynctask result. Should I call the asynctask in onCreateView or somewhere else ? Making the call in onCreateView would invoke the asynctask more times as the orientation would change, as I am aware of. So what is the best practice for fragments with asynctask ?

Comment: Refer to below thread
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15079948/guideline-to-choose-among-asynctaskloader-and-asynctask-to-be-used-in-fragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better to use [`AsyncTaskLoader`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html) instead [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) with fragments

Answer (score 0):

When you create the Asynctask in onCreate it gets called only when the fragment is created. When you call it in onResume it gets called even after the user returns gets a phone message. So it depends on how up to date you want the data.

You could even call it in onViewCreated but it really is up to you. You can also call it in the application object so the asynctask is executed only when the user starts the app.