# Why asynctask precessing is direct and loader processing indirect?

Tags: android

I am reading google doc and I found these lines, But I am unable to understand the difference between these two statements 
Why asynctask precessing is direct and loader processing indirect?

[Reference](https://google-developer-training.github.io/android-developer-fundamentals-course-concepts-v2/unit-3-working-in-the-background/lesson-7-background-tasks/7-1-c-asynctask-and-asynctaskloader/7-1-c-asynctask-and-asynctaskloader.html)

There are several ways to do background processing in Android. Two of those ways are:

1. You can do background processing directly, using the AsyncTask
   class.
2. You can do background processing indirectly, using the Loader
       framework and then the AsyncTaskLoader class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The AsyncTaskLoader add a level of abstraction that handles some configuration changes.

When the reference say **directly** it means that you have to handle all configuration changes by yourself because you are using explicitly a Task.
If you use a Loader instead you don't have to manage these cases, because it's doing some stuff for you, so it **indirectly** handles the background processing and you don't have to worry about configuration changes (e.g. a rotation during a network call).

Just read this thread for more information about the differences between the two:

[AsyncLoader vs AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7120813/asynctaskloader-vs-asynctask)

Hope this helps.

Cheers.