# Can't access getContentResolver() from context?

Tags: java, android, parameters, crash, android-context

I have two classes, `MainActivity` and `DoHardWork`. DoHardWork extends `AsyncTask`, and in the class I need to access a context in order to get the `contentResolver` and do a query.

No problem, right? Let's just pass it as a parameter to `DoHardWork`:

```
    Context currCont = this;
    new DoHardWork(currCont).execute();
```

Then in the constructor I grab the context and store it in a global variable called `ccc`.

But as soon as I try to access the context it crashes, with no errors that make sense.

```
try {
    Cursor cursor = ccc.getContentResolver().query(
            Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), null, null, null, null);
}
catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("apptag", e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

All I get is:

```
05-18 18:54:06.725: E/apptag(29063): Crashed
05-18 18:54:06.725: E/apptag(29063): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-18 18:54:06.725: E/apptag(29063):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getContentResolver(ContextWrapper.java:91)
05-18 18:54:06.725: E/apptag(29063):    at se.jbhalmstad.ndroid.DoHardWork.getTextMessages(DoHardWork.java:214)
05-18 18:54:06.725: E/apptag(29063):    at se.jbhalmstad.ndroid.DoHardWork.returnResults(DoHardWork.java:114)
05-18 18:54:06.725: E/apptag(29063):    at se.jbhalmstad.ndroid.DoHardWork.doInBackground(DoHardWork.java:55)
05-18 18:54:06.725: E/apptag(29063):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
05-18 18:54:06.725: E/apptag(29063):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
05-18 18:54:06.725: E/apptag(29063):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
05-18 18:54:06.725: E/apptag(29063):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
05-18 18:54:06.725: E/apptag(29063):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
05-18 18:54:06.725: E/apptag(29063):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Why can't I access the context?

Comment: I don't think e.printStackTrace prints to the log.  However, little known fact, you can pass the exception as a parameter to the log statement.  Try Log.e("apptag", "Crashed!", e);  and see if you get some more useful output.

Comment: It did print to the log. I get the same exception if i pass it as a parameter to Log.e(). I updated first post with the entire exception, if it helps.

Comment: Instead of storing the `Context` passed as argument, try calling `getApplicationContext()` on it.

Comment: Is the code you posted the "returnResults" method, or the "getTextMessages" one?

Comment: @K-ballo, it crashes as soon as i try to call getApplicationContext on ccc.

Comment: @Alexander, i kind of cheated a little bit when i explained to make it simpler. From doInBackground() i call returnResults() which then calls getTextMessages(), and then it crashes. It crashes as soon as i try to do anything with the context (ccc), no matter where i am in the class. The code i posted is in getTextMessages().

Comment: Alright, now i feel stupid. The problem isn't in the DoHardWork class at all. It's in the MainActivity. The problem is that i can't get the context. If i try getApplicationContext() or this.getApplicationContext() it crashes. Any ideas? It extends Activity, so i should have access to the context right? Here's the MainActivity class: http://pastebin.com/uyTJ9HZC

Comment: @qwerty If it extends Activity then why don't you simply try 'this' to get activity context. Trying to get application context using getApplicationContext() sometimes doesn't work without any valid reason.

Comment: It does indeed extend Activity. It's really weird, i don't get it. Even if i do this.getContentResolver().query(...) it fails.

Comment: Solved the problem. Read the answer i posted if you want to know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem.

The way it works is that from the MainActivity class, i set a repeating AlarmManager. When the alarm goes off the GetOperations class acts as a BroadcastReceiver and gets executed. Because i need the heavy work in an AsyncTask class i have all of that in a class called DoHardWork. (Yes, i know the names are bad and most of the coding needs improvement anyways) But i can't call DoHardWork from the BroadcastReceiver, i need to call it from MainActivity. So instead of trying to call it from BroadcastReceiver i then create a new instance of MainActivity and call a method in there which then calls DoHardWork. That's where i made the problem. MainActivity isn't static, so when i made a new instance of it there was no context.

What i ended up doing is passing a context from BroadcastReceiver to MainActivity.

This probably got very messy while explaining, but i hope you get the gist of it. Thank you for all the help!