# Is is right approach to use AsyncTaskLoader , which purpose is to clear external storage?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-loadermanager, android-loader, asynctaskloader

When application opens, splash screen is displayed and in the background I clean directory on external storage if it is exists, as soon as the directory is removed, another activity should be start.
I was using AsyncTask, as ASyncTask is not handling configuration changes ,etc ,I want to use AsyncTaskLoader is it good idea,
I mean if in the separate thread , I am trying to do cleaning action, and I am not fetching any data,what kind of threading mechanism I need to use?

Comment: What do you mean by `ASyncTask is not handling configuration changes`

Comment: well asyncTask is also on a separate thread, you know that right?

Comment: @Petro read this you will understand http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7120813/asynctaskloader-vs-asynctask

Comment: @Petro
When the phone is rotated the activity is destroyed ,while ASyncTask is not, I need on my own  destroy  AsyncTask, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes i think AsyncTask is a good choice here. You can check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964011/handler-vs-asynctask-vs-thread) on SO for differences between AsyncTask , Handler and Thread for detailed pro/cons list. AsyncTask are appropriate for background processes that dont need to communicate with the UI thread and are tightly coupled with the activity (unlike an IntentService). Though for network operations nowdays volley is preffered over AsyncTask

Comment: If item onClick I delete sources from external storage ,and as  a result  the list should be notified as the item is removed ,in this case(when separate thread has interaction with UI Thread)  AsyncTask  is the right choice?

Comment: Well these kind of questions really depend on very specific details, but generally speaking and without any more info provided i would suggest you use handlers. read this to understand why i recommend handlers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523459/handler-vs-asynctask

Comment: The main problem for me, is to handle configuration change and with AsyncTask and HandlerThread it could be problematic. Even taking into account that fact is it worth to use it?
What kind of details you need?